# Can't figure out how to scrape data in body tag using beautiful soup (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

r = urllib.urlopen('https://www.vrbo.com/576329').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
rate = soup.find_all('body')

print rate
print type(soup)
```

I'm trying to capture values in containers such as data-bedrooms="3", specifically the values given in the quotations, but I have no idea what they are formally called or how to parse them.

The below is a sample of part of the print out for the "body" so I know the values are there, the capturing the specific part is what I can't get:

data-ratemaximum="$260" data-rateminimum="$220" data-rateunits="night" data-rawlistingnumber="576329" data-requestuuid="73bcfaa3-9637-40a8-801c-ae86f93caf39" data-searchpdptab="C" data-serverday="18" data-showbookingphone="False"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick apart your result.  It might be helpful to know that those things you seek are called *attributes* of a *tag* in HTML:

```
body_tag = rate[0]
data_bedrooms = body_tag.attrs['data-bedrooms']
```

The code above assumes you only have one `<body>` -- if you have more you will need to use a `for` loop on `rate`.  You'll also possibly want to convert the value to an integer with `int()`.

Comment: In this case there was only one body, but yes that would be true, so thank you for pointing that out. Also, the data_bedrooms = body_tag.attrs['data-bedrooms'] was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ahh got it! So they are attributes!

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the value of an attribute used rate [ 'attr'], example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

r = urllib.urlopen('https://www.vrbo.com/576329').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
rate = soup.find('body')
print rate['data-ratemaximum']
print rate['data-rateunits']
print rate['data-rawlistingnumber']
print rate['data-requestuuid']
print rate['data-searchpdptab']
print rate['data-serverday']
print rate['data-searchpdptab']
print rate['data-showbookingphone']

print rate
print type(soup)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Carlos!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you wanted *only* `data-bedrooms` from the `soup` object or not. I did some cursory checking of the output produce and was able to reason that the `data-*` items you mentioned were attributes, rather than tags. If doc structure is consistent, you could probably locate the respective tag associated with the attribute, and make finding these more efficient:

```
import re
# regex pattern for attribs
data_tag_pattern = re.compile('^data\-')

# Create list of attribs
attribs_wanted = "data-bedrooms data-rateminimumdata-rateunits data-rawlistingnumber data-requestuuid data-searchpdptab data-serverday data-showbookingphone".split()


# Search entire tree
for item in soup.findAll():
    # Use descendants to recurse downwards
    for child in item.descendants:
        try:
            for attribute in child.attrs:
                if data_tag_pattern.match(attribute) and attribute in attribs_wanted:
                    print("{}: {}".format(attribute, child[attribute]))
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

This will produce output as so:

```
data-showbookingphone: False
data-bedrooms: 3
data-requestuuid: 2b6f4d21-8b04-403d-9d25-0a660802fb46
data-serverday: 18
data-rawlistingnumber: 576329
data-searchpdptab: C
```

hth!

Comment: I ended up using this code to find some other data I was looking for, so thanks again!